# How to restore game progress in OS 9.1 after reinstalling deleted app

Tags: iphone, game-center

I reinstalled a deleted app (Angry Birds) from iCloud but the progress stored in Game Center was not updated. How do I get it back? I don't want to start over.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of deleting the app there was a popup: "Remove Angry Birds from Game Center?  You will no longer be listed on leaderboards for Angry Birds.  Keep / Remove".

If you clicked "Remove", there is no possibly recovery for your game data in iCloud.